# Stata. How to create unique identifiers using labels if values are random?

Tags: label, uniqueidentifier, stata

I have a huge panel data set (1950-2012).

```
state   year    income
    AL  2000    100
    AK  2001    200
    AZ  2002    150
    ...
    AL  2003    120
    AK  2004    10
    AZ  2005    150
    ...
```

The problem is that the variable `state` can take up different values in different years (but labels do not change!). For example in 2001 value for label `AL` is `10`, but in 2003 value for label `AL` is `20`.

How can I create unique identifier, say a new variable `stateID` that would take an integer value for all `AL` labels regardless of the year? `egen stateID = group(state)` does not help. Is there any other way?

Comment: For "unique" read "distinct", as discussed in http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0042 No doubt I am out of step with the majority here, or at least with SO tagging, but unique identifiers (should) occur just once each. Unix took a wrong turning with the `uniq` command, perhaps because they were going for short names whenever possible, and `dist` would not appeal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That calls for investigation of how it happened and whether the data can be trusted. But in terms of Stata technique, first `decode`, then `encode` again. Demonstration:

```
. set obs 3
obs was 0, now 3

. gen numid = _n

. label define numid 1 "AL" 2 "AL" 3 "AL"

. label values numid numid

. list

     +-------+
     | numid |
     |-------|
  1. |    AL |
  2. |    AL |
  3. |    AL |
     +-------+

. decode numid, gen(strid)

. list

    +---------------+
    | numid   strid |
    |---------------|
 1. |    AL      AL |
 2. |    AL      AL |
 3. |    AL      AL |
    +---------------+

 . encode strid, gen(newnumid)

 . list

      +--------------------------+
      | numid   strid   newnumid |
      |--------------------------|
   1. |    AL      AL         AL |
   2. |    AL      AL         AL |
   3. |    AL      AL         AL |
     +--------------------------+

    . list, nolabels

      +--------------------------+
      | numid   strid   newnumid |
      |--------------------------|
   1. |     1      AL          1 |
   2. |     2      AL          1 |
   3. |     3      AL          1 |
      +--------------------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
egen stateID = group(state), label
```

Comment: As far I know, this will create separate groups for `AL == 10` and `AL == 20`.